# Connecting to server via VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel, gre

There is a server with connection via VPN to it (using GRE protocol). I have got a problem to connect to this VPN from home network, because GRE is not allowed by provider. But I have got another work server (with SSH connection to it from home) in other network from which I can connect to server in VPN. Is there any way to make tunnel to connect from home to VPN-server through work-server? SSH connection is anouth for me. Home computer and work-server have ubuntu operating system, vpn-server is under centos.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely possible. As you are telling that you need an SSH only, probably the most easy way would be to set up a GRE connection from your "another work server" (let's call it `Server B`) to your first server which accepts GRE (calling it `Server A`). Once you've done it and it can SSH from `Server B` to `Server A` you can just chain it from your home. I.e. first connection to `Server B` SSH and then just SSH to a `Server A` from there.

If you would like to have SSH connection without that chain, you have to set up some sort of routing and/or port forwarding (NAT) on the `Server B`. Exact configuration are greatly dependent on your configuration and would be out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Once you can reach the work server you can easily do that.

---

Assumption for the example

- source system (at home) : 10.0.0.1
- work system (jump server) : 10.0.0.2 (ssh is running on standard port 22/TCP)
- destination server : 10.0.0.3 (ssh is running on standard port 22/TCP)

---

1. port forward via server B

With opening the ssh tunnel you can set local port forward (**-L [<local_addr>:]<local_port>:<remote_addr_to_forward_to>:<remote_port_to_forward_to>** ). Then you can open another ssh connection pointing <local_addr> but with parameter **-p <local_port>** or the first tunnel. With this configuration:

- the first tunnel have to be up to the rest is working
- you can have more connection over the first tunnel (more ssh connections, scp connection,...)

```
(1) ssh -L 10022:10.0.0.3:22 10.0.0.2
(2) ssh -p 10022 127.0.0.1
(3) scp -P 10022 <local_file> 127.0.0.1:<destination_file>
```

```
+-----+        +-----+        +-----+
|  A  |=== 1 ==|  B  |        |  C  |
|     | -- 2 - | -2- | - 2 -> |     |
|     | -- 3 - | -3- | - 3 -> |     |
|     |========|     |        |     |
+-----+        +-----+        +-----+
10.0.0.1       10.0.0.2       10.0.0.3
```

2. **native** ssh connection using "native" jump host

ssh offer "native" support for this kind of connection using **-J <destination>** parameter. For the specification of *destination* is recommended to use config (~./ssh/config) file.

The example of the code would be (the outer connection is "transparent")

```
(1) ssh -J 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.3
```

```
+-----+        +-----+        +-----+
|  A  |========|  B  |        |  C  |
|     | -- 1 - | -1- | - 1 -> |     |
|     |========|     |        |     |
+-----+        +-----+        +-----+
10.0.0.1       10.0.0.2       10.0.0.3
```